# How to add "public" by default to cached views by Django?

Tags: django, django-cache, google-cloud-cdn

Im trying to use Google Cloud CDN to cache Django responses. Django properly sets the cache-control header with the max age, but it is missing the 'public' part of the header.

Basically, currently all cached views have:

```
cache-control: max-age=3600
```

But I want:

```
cache-control: max-age=3600,public
```

Edit:
My current settings.py have the following for caching:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    ...
]

....

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 3600
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ''
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": os.environ.get('CACHE_URL'),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            "IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS": True,
            "MAX_ENTRIES": 10000,
        }
    }
}
```

So I basically followed https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/. So I cached the entire site. And for those views which I don't want cached I use `@never_cache`.

Edit 2:
I could add "public=True" to each view with an annotation but I want a solution for the entire site.

Comment: Exactly how did you set this?

Comment: Added my settings

Comment: Have you also considered using the “Cache All Static” cache mode, which will cache web assets (but not your HTML) per https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cache-modes - ?

Comment: I have some API calls that should be cached as well. So it is not just static assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I ended up just going for a simple middleware. Though I am open for suggestions.

```
class PublicCacheMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        if response.has_header('Cache-Control') and 'private' not in response.get('Cache-Control'):
            response['Cache-Control'] += ',public'

        return response
```